# Verbose specification of exact Table or Implied

Tags: design, design-patterns, sql, sql-server

Consider the following two queries in SQL (Transact SQL):

```
UPDATE [database_name].[dbo].[table_name]
SET [database_name].[dbo].[table_name].[field_name] = @value
WHERE [database_name].[dbo].[table_name].[field_name] = @searchvalue
```

and the alternative

```
UPDATE [database_name].[dbo].[table_name]
SET field_name = @value
WHERE field_name = @searchvalue
```

Which one of those is preferable? Both work the same from what I can tell. From a design standpoint, is one superior to the other? Why?

Specifically in the context of a very large (500+ lines, spread across multiple databases and tables) stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are functionally exactly the same.

The second is (greatly) preferred for readability.

The only possible justification for fully specifying everything is to remove ambiguity if you have multiple tables, but even in that case, it would be better style to use table aliases rather than the full names (again for readability purposes).

Answer (score 4):

The second is generally more readable and therefore better to use. the first option repeats a lot of information that takes up screen space and forces you to continually filter out that repeated information which can cause you to miss the important information of the column names.

Furthermore it's generally a good idea to only specify only things that could potentially be different. Your database name isn't going to be different unless calling a remote database, so by not using it everywhere it becomes apparent where those type of things are happening.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to writing administrative or other housekeeping/data maintenance scripts, being explicit is a good practice especially if you're running them from SQL Server Management Studio where the connection and database selection are a little more ad hoc and manual. There are ways (USE statement) to declare the database to cut down on your code getting too verbose.

If you're writing application code in SQL Server there are other ways in your connection to determine the server instance and database, so you can get away without writing them in your code if they're not required. Just like using a table alias helps with readability. Always include schema.